# UseState too many re-renders in initial load

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following problem:
I have a list of machines and need to know if they are in use or free to use. When they are free to use, they can be reserved.

Now I tried to save the current state in a useState and with a click of a button change that state to reserved if it is free.

The thing is, when the site is first loaded, the state is set multiple times for each machine, and that results in too many re-renders.

useEffect did not help, because in a worst-case-scenario there are 100 machines and they all have a different state, so the state is set 100 times.

This is the Code responsible for the error (shortened):

```
  
    return (
      <Card w="80%" ml="10%" mt={buildingProps.marginTop} boxShadow="0">
        <CardTitle>{buildingProps.buildingName}</CardTitle>
  
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            //TABLE HEADERS
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {buildingProps.workStations.map((station: Workstation, index: any) => {

              //variables are declared here in use for the table

              setstatus(station.status) //Reason for too many re-renders

              

              return (
                <TableRow key={stationName}>
                  <TableCell className={`stationStatus-${index}`} w="150px" ref={ref}>
                
                    {checkStation(status)} //Creates a colored statusicon

                  </TableCell>

                  //Workstation information is filled in here

                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className="reservationButton">
                    <Button variantColor="teal" onClick={() => {
                      let isReserved = reserveStation(reservedStation, buildingProps.setReservationInfo);
                      buildingProps.setShow(isReserved); 
                      isReserved ? setstatus(statusValue.reserved) : setstatus(statusValue.inUse);
                      }}>
                      Reserve
                    </Button> 
/**On Button click the function reserveStation checks if the station can be reserved. If it returns true a Box with the information about the reserved station is shown (setShow) and the statusValue is changed to reserved which should result in a new statusicon. If it cannot be reserved the station is blocked at the moment.**/
```

Is there a way in react to handle this kind of situation? Apart from useEffect I havent found anything useful.

I thought about giving the checkStation function a second status, the initial status. But then the enum statusValue needs a fourth status, just so I can tell checkStation to actually use the useState instead of initialState.

Thank you everyone.

**I have to use react in strict mode!**

Comment: `setstatus(station.status) //Reason for too many re-renders` - You're not calling this on a button click, you're calling this every time during the render.  So rendering is updating state, which triggers rendering, which triggers updating state, which triggers rendering, etc.  Did you just want to remove this line of code?  What is the intent of trying to update state on every render?

Comment: @David when the website is loaded initially I need to load all the stations and their respective status. So they have the right icon shown. I used to have it just be in a variable. 
When I remove this ALL station will have the initial status that is set, whatever it is. So either all are free, in use or reserved. 
On button click I do call setstatus, isReserved ? setstatus(statusValue.reserved) : setstatus(statusValue.inUse);

Comment: Well, to solve the current problem you should simply remove the `setstatus(station.status)` call that's *not* in the button click.  Because it's causing an endless render loop.  Then it sounds like the *original* problem was that you are trying to store multiple "status" values in a single variable.  If there are multiple values then an array sounds more appropriate.  Likely an array of objects with keys and values so you're not relying on something as arbitrary as index position.